# Modify the values of 4 columns based on certain values in one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset where I have 5 columns and multiple rows.

Need to multiply values based on state

Im struck with the logic to execute this, because of the mathematical operations to be performed .

All the examples given, were to create new columns based on set of conditions but this needs modification in existing column.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are using `&` instead of `and`. The former performs a bitwise AND, which does not appear to be what you want here. I would also recommend taking the index calculation out of the `[ ]` and put it in a variable, for readability and the ability to validate.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
    ['Liquid', 1, 2, 21, 22],
    ['Liquid', 23, 24, 5, 6],
    ['Gas/Vapour', 27, 28, 7, 8],
    ['Gas', 9, 10, 11, 12]
    ], columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'])

liquid_row_indices = df[df['col1'] == 'Liquid'].index.tolist()
gas_vapour__row_indices = df[df['col1'] == 'Gas/Vapour'].index.tolist()


df.iloc[liquid_row_indices, 1:] = df.iloc[liquid_row_indices, 1:].applymap(
                                  lambda x: x*1000 if x<20 else x)

df.iloc[gas_vapour__row_indices, 1:] = df.iloc[gas_vapour__row_indices, 1:].applymap(
                                       lambda x: x*1.024 if x<20 else x)
```

The output will be:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
0   Liquid  1000    2000    21.000  22.000
1   Liquid  23  24  5000.000    6000.000
2   Gas/Vapour  27  28  7.168   8.192
3   Gas 9   10  11.000  12.000
```

To summarise the logic:

1) We are storing the row numbers where the state is equal to 'Fluid' and to 'Gas/Vapour'

2) Then for these rows in a data frame, for all columns (except the 1st one), we `applymap` the lambda function and replace the original value with the one returned by the lambda function.

3) The lambda function will check if the value is < 20, if yes it would multiply the value by 1000 (for Liquid state) or by 1.024 (for Gas/Vapour state), if no then it returns the same value as the original.